# Espresso поиск текста в UI

Tags: android, espresso

Здравствуйте, подскажите как найти *текст в UI*. Например этот текст находится в **Snackbar**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Стандартно никак, вы только можете реализовать свой поиск. Я бы сделал это примерно так: делаете свой отдельный класс, который принимал бы на вход основной ViewGroup из основного Layout-а, далее пробегался бы по каждому View элементу и методом toString() получал бы стринговое содержание View элементов, а уже потом с этими String наборами работал бы поиском, там уже подходят обычные String функции, которые хорошо ищут текст. А вообще такую фичу стандартно реализовали в 6 версии андроид, но насколько я знаю там нету выделенной API под это, просто есть функционал для юзера